# In IBM Cloud Databases, is there a way to see disk size for a postgres instance by using the ibmcloud cli?

Tags: postgresql, ibm-cloud

I have a Postgres deployment on IBM Cloud Databases and I am trying to programatically obtain the resources used by it, i.e. disk, RAM and CPU. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the IBM Cloud CLI to query the resources in your deployment.
You need the [CLI itself](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/cli) and the [cloud databases plugin](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-plug-ins).
You then use the `groups` command to obtain the resources list for your deployment:

```bash
ibmcloud cdb groups <CRN> --json
```

You will get an output like this:

```
{
 "groups": [
  {
   "id": "member",
   "count": 2,
   "memory": {
    "units": "mb",
    "allocation_mb": 2048,
    "minimum_mb": 2048,
    "step_size_mb": 256,
    "is_adjustable": true
   },
   "cpu": {
    "units": "count",
    "allocation_count": 0,
    "minimum_count": 6,
    "step_size_count": 2,
    "is_adjustable": true
   },
   "disk": {
    "units": "mb",
    "allocation_mb": 10240,
    "minimum_mb": 10240,
    "step_size_mb": 1024,
    "is_adjustable": true
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

The CRN is the unique identifier of your Cloud Databases deployment.

The above command is generic to all database deployments, i.e. will also work for MySQL, MongoDB, Elastic and other [IBM Cloud Databases](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/databases)